# Single Page Application for multi-type users

Tags: angularjs, frontend, single-page-application

I am building a web application which has three types of users: visitors, companies, and admins.

I wonder what is the best way for implementing the front-end based on AngularJS. Should I have one SPA for all users or create a separate SPA for each type?

Note that each type has different UI (menus, tables, ..), different permissions, and different routing...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that each type of user has a different UI and different routing, I would say it's best to separate their front-ends. A front-end is after all just an interface to your application, and you seem to say the interface is totally different for all three.

Different routing doesn't make sense to me though. It should not be a problem to have one set of route definitions that fits all. If the UI is in fact not completely different, but has a lot of overlap, I would say it's better to make one SPA and create a generic set of (computed) observables that you can use to show/hide the correct parts of the UI to each user type.

If you want a better answer, you need to supply more information. Because you tell us very little, the answer will be very vague, since it all depends on the exact use case.